# Find sum of each adjecent number and finally print second largest highest sum and two adjecent numbers from this came

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem statement is find sum of each adjacent numbers and finally print second highest sum and two adjacent numbers from this came.

Condition - Only one loop.

```
public class AdjencentSumOfWithSecondHighest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] arr = {2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 1, 7};

            int[] newArr = new int[arr.length - 1];

            int highest = arr[0], previoushighest = highest;

            int index = 0, prevIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                newArr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];

                if(highest < newArr[i]){
                    previoushighest = highest;
                    highest = newArr[i];


                    prevIndex = index;

                    index = i;              
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Second Highest NO : "+previoushighest);

            System.out.println("no one is "+arr[prevIndex]+ " and no two is "+arr[index]);

        }
    }
```

Working very good. But if in array there is duplicate numbers then wrong result like {2, 5, 3, 3, 8, 9, 1, 7}

Comment: Your code would break in case of non-duplicate numbers as well. Consider the array {8,0,1,2,3}

Comment: really! let me check

Comment: Yes :( its not working what is solution

Comment: I could not find the problem with duplicate values. What is the problem with the result for {2, 5, 3, 3, 8, 9, 1, 7}??

Comment: this input {2, 5, 3,  3, 9, 1, 7}

Comment: You don't handle situations where your second highest is occuring after you have already found the highest.

Comment: You are right. I will try. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me.. atleast for the cases discussed so far (Not sure yet for completeness).

```
    int[] arr = { 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7,8};

    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length - 1];

    int highest = arr[0], previoushighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int index = 0; // to capture position of second highest pair's second element
    int hindex = 0; // to capture position of highest pair's second element

    if(arr.length < 3) {
        System.out.println("No second highest exists");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];

        if(previoushighest < newArr[i]){
            if(highest < newArr[i]){
                previoushighest = highest;
                highest = newArr[i];
                index = hindex;
                hindex = i+1;
            } else if(highest != newArr[i]) {
                previoushighest = newArr[i];
                index = i+1;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Second Highest NO : "+previoushighest);

    System.out.println("no one is "+arr[index-1]+ " and no two is "+arr[index]);
```

Comment: Yes, it is working but not sure for all conditions. still i will accept it as answer. Thank You.

Comment: Found problem with my earlier code. Updated with correction and after incorporating idea from @Md. Bhuiyan

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED: NEW**

This may help you.

```
int[] arr =  { 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7 }   ;

    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length - 1];

    int highest = arr[0]+arr[1], previoushighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int index = 0, prevIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];


        if (highest < newArr[i]) {
            int temp=highest;
            highest = newArr[i];

            previoushighest=temp;
            index = i;
        }

        else if( previoushighest < newArr[i] && highest>newArr[i]){
            previoushighest=newArr[i];
            prevIndex=i;
        }


    }

    System.out.println("Second Highest NO : " + previoushighest);
    System.out.println("Highest NO : " + highest);

    System.out.println("no one is " + arr[prevIndex] + " and no two is "
            + arr[index]);
```

I don't understand. why this line you are printing

```
System.out.println("no one is " + arr[prevIndex] + " and no two is "
                + arr[index]);
```

Comment: Wrong....what about this input { 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7 }

Comment: Nope.. it's still won't work for {8,0,1,2,3}

Comment: Ok. I am checking and will update my answer soon

Comment: Check this. I updated my answer. this is working for all conditions. @SagarYadav

Comment: Check this. I updated my answer. this is working for all conditions. @AnupamJain

Comment: No it's not working. Even for the given array in your program itself it's giving incorrect result. Second highest should be 7 while it's giving 6.

Comment: The one you've used in the code: { 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 7 }

Comment: I think now its working fine @AnupamJain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117892/discussion-between-anupam-jain-and-md-nasir-uddin-bhuiyan).